# DocumentFile : problems creating specific directory name

Tags: android, android-sdcard, documentfile

I have an app that has to create files and directories on the removable sdcard. I use the [DocumentFile API](http://oper.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/provider/DocumentFile.html). In most of cases, it works, but I have found one case which doesn't work (at least on a Samsung GS7):

I cannot create a directory named "**R.E.M.**" (without quotes).

Test case: I'm working in directory "/storage/9C33-6BBD/Xxxx", I want to create directory "R.E.M."

```
DocumentFile parentDf;
// init of parentDf to point to /storage/9C33-6BBD/Xxxx
DocumentFile remDf = df.createDirectory("R.E.M.");
if(remDf == null)
    displayMessage("failure");
else
    displayMessage("success");
```

This will display "*success*", so I'm Happy. Latter I want to create a file in this directory: "R.E.M./myfile".

```
DocumentFile parentDf;
// init of parentDf to point to /storage/9C33-6BBD/Xxxx
DocumentFile remDf = parentDf.findFile("R.E.M.");
if(remDf == null) {
    displayMessage("failure : R.E.M. doesn't exists");
    return false;
}

DocumentFile myfileDf = remDf.createFile("text/plain","myfile");
if(remDf == null)
    displayMessage("failure");
else
    displayMessage("success");
```

This will display "*failure: R.E.M. doesn't exists*"

so I list files with DocumentFile.listFiles and see: "R.E.M" (**the last DOT has gone away !**)

if I do `(new File("/storage/9C33-6BBD/Xxxx/R.E.M.")).exists()` it returns true!

If I take a look with "adb shell"

```
hero2lte:/storage/9C33-6BBD/Xxxx $ ls -la                                                                                                       
total 768
drwxrwx--x  3 root sdcard_rw 131072 2017-07-19 14:18 .
drwxrwx--x 17 root sdcard_rw 131072 2017-07-19 13:31 ..
drwxrwx--x  2 root sdcard_rw 131072 2017-07-19 13:46 R.E.M

hero2lte:/storage/9C33-6BBD/Xxxx $ ls -lad R.E.M.                                                                                               
drwxrwx--x 2 root sdcard_rw 131072 2017-07-19 13:46 R.E.M.
```

**Does anyone know where I can find documentation about directories displayName limitations?**

thanks

Comment: The limitations are up to the storage provider. I am not aware of any storage provider that has documented what it will and will not accept.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is not a DocumentFile API limitation, but simply a filesystem limitation : Microsoft filesystems (at least VFAT and NTFS) doesn't support directories names ending with a DOT (.) .